# install IO::Socket::SSL with version>=2.007 at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Net/SMTP.pm line 270, <FIN> line 3

Tags: git, email, ssl, socket.io, git-bash

I hope anyone can help me for this issue

Once try to use command git `send-email -1` to send email via git-bash I got the error

**Not using SSL_VERIFY_PEER due to out-of-date IO::Socket::SSL.
To use SSL please install IO::Socket::SSL with version>=2.007 at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Net/SMTP.pm line 270,  line 3.**

I want to solve this issue to send email --

I have tried to install pacman, -module.pl, Net::SSLeay and perl -MCPAN -e 'install "IO::Socket::SSL"' but I can’t install them anyway

Git installed in windows 10 OS